# Как работает 3d графика?

Tags: 3d

Я уже недавно делал пример 3d игры, только там суть была в том что игрок находиться в 2d измерении
он выпускает например 30 лучей, и каждому лучу соответствует определенная область на игровом экране, ну тоесть таких областей 30 если лучей 30.  И когда игрок столкнулся с припятствием то область соответствующая данному лучу на игровом экране загораеться, и от растояния этого столкновения высчитываеться прозрачность, и высота области закрашываемая. вот пример:
[image: 3d графика]
Ну это псевдо графика, я бы хотел узнать как работает настоящий движок 3d. можете обьеснить простыми словами, или скинуть материал (на русском) где об этом рассказываеться.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/248153/

Comment: Кроме растеризации, которая описывается по ссылке, которую привел @gbg, есть еще методы бросания лучей (ray casting). Это совершенно другой подход. Фундаментальный труд по этой теме — “Computer Graphics
Principles and Practice”, на английском, но можно воспользоваться переводчиком.

Comment: Вот тут можно посмотреть доступно, как работает ray casting о котором упомянул @eanmos - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTqLX0OHZzI